# Does TransferFunctionModel have to be finite dimensional?

Tags: control-systems

Does `TransferFunctionModel` have to be finite dimensional? Or can we for example use *Mathematica* to make a `BodePlot` of a transfer function that is not in rational pole-zero form?

I understand that *Mathematica* can deal with delays, but I'm thinking of more general infinite-dimensional transfer functions, for example the Laplace transform of a $\operatorname{sinc}$.

Answer (score 2):

a short answer

```
 pars=Rationalize[{L-> 6.9,A->0.0133,a0->410,
       c1a->0.003,c2a->0.002,c1p->-2.5 10^-6,c2p->4.3 10^-6}];
```

With the transfer function

```
G[s_]=(a0 c1a (A Cosh[(L s)/a0]+a0 c2p Sinh[(L s)/a0]))/
      (A a0 (-c1p+c2p) Cosh[(L s)/a0]+(A^2-a0^2 c1p c2p) Sinh[(L s)/a0]);
```

Bodeplot:

```
Grid[{{LogLogPlot[Evaluate[20Log10[Abs[#]]&/@{G[I 2 Pi f]}/.pars],
   {f,1,200},
   ImageSize->Large,GridLines->Automatic,AspectRatio->1/3,
   PlotRange->Full,Frame->True,PlotLegends->{"|G(s)|"}]},
   {LogLinearPlot[Evaluate[Arg[#]180/Pi&/@{G[I 2 Pi f]}/.pars],
   {f,1,200},ImageSize->Large,ExclusionsStyle->Gray,
   GridLines->Automatic,AspectRatio->1/3,PlotRange->Full,
   Frame->True,PlotLegends->{"arg{G(s)}",""}]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately the "code" mode hides the lines, is there a way of fixing?

Comment: What lines do you mean?

Comment: pars=Rationalize[{...; G[s_]=(a0 c1a (A...; and Grid[{{LogLogPlot[E; they get cut when the page wraps.

Comment: You can scroll right. At least I can (in Chrome)

Comment: I opened in a different computer and it reads beautifully! (Curious bug in one of my systems, probably I'll never find out what's wrong.) Thanks!